# Recursive addition of values in the directed tree

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, tree, directed-graph

Good morning, 
 I have data structured as a tree. Each node in it except the root has attribute - 'proportion relative to the parent node'. But just leaves have extra attribute 'value'. What I would like to do is to write a function that would calculate values for the all nodes in the tree. 
For instance, in the image below they will be calculated like this:

```
value of b= 5*0.3 + 6*0.7 = 5.7;
value of c= 7*1 = 7;
value of d = 8*0.5+9*0.4+10*0.1=8.6;
value of a = 5.7*0.3+7*0.4+8.6*0.3=7.09;
```

I assume from the nature of the data structure - that this function that sets values of the nodes - should be recursive. 
Will be gratefull if someone provides description, pseudocode or function in python. 
Here is the image of the tree:
[image: data structure]

Now following the suggestion of Srinivas I have tried:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search import dfs_tree
t=nx.DiGraph()

nds=[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b","proportion":"0.3"},{"name":"c","proportion":"0.4"},{"name":"d","proportion":"0.3"},{"name":"e","proportion":"0.3","value":"5"},{"name":"f","proportion":"0.7","value":"6"},{"name":"g","proportion":"1","value":"7"},{"name":"h","proportion":"0.5","value":"8"},{"name":"i","proportion":"0.4","value":"9"},{"name":"j","proportion":"0.1","value":"10"}]
for nd in nds:
 t.add_node(nd['name'],**nd)

eds=[('a','b'),('a','c'),('a','d'),('b','e'),('b','f'),('c','g'),('d','h'),('d','i'),('d','j')]
for ed in eds:
 t.add_edge(ed[0],ed[1])

def answer(node):
    if node not in t: # no tree
        return 0
    if len(list(t.successors(node)))==0: # leaf
        return float(t.node[node]['value'])
    value_list = []
    for child in list(t.successors(node)):
        value_list.append(float(t.node[child]['proportion']) * answer(child))
    t.node[node]['value']=sum(value_list)

answer('a')
```

But it gives an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType' . I think for some reason it can just do one brunch - a->b->e a->b->f but can't go to the next one...

Comment: Recursive is good start, what stopping you from implementing one?

Comment: 2Pham Trung. I don't have much experience with writting recursive functions and also I am not 100% sure that it will work. There are two types of operations needed here. At first you need to find all leaves that are under root a. And after you need to start going back from the leaves adding the numbers level by level... So I have tried for couple of hours to come up with something - didn't work - so I ask here.

Comment: Why don't you just start from your code instead? Alright, at least you have showed that you have some thoughts. The nature of recursive is to break down the problem into small parts, so, in order to solve this problem, imagine that you have a tree with only two levels, how would you do it?

Comment: So if I understand well the concept of recursion the base case in the function will be this:

if len(list(tree.successors(node)))==0:
  return g.node[node]['value']);

Basically if it is leave return its value... But what will be in 'else:' part of the function I can't imagine...

Comment: You are inexperience, and you are rushing too fast, let just focus on two levels first, ok? Hint: for 2 level, you just need to get the value of all successors. How about the value of the successor is the result of your recursive function with the parameter is each successor node?

Comment: thank you. give me a minute.

Comment: Issue a print statement before the multiplication that tells you which child ID being operated upon to determine what the problem is

Comment: it breaks on node 'f' . but this leaf has all needed attributes...

Comment: but if I do answer('b') it works...it defines b value correctly... so if it needs to go just one hierarchy level - it works well. but if there are several levels - it fails for some reason...

Comment: Issue 2 print statements
`print child`
`print answer(child)` right before the multiplication step.  tell us what the output is.

Comment: In any case, read up on post order traversals of trees. this is definitely a post order traversal.

Comment: thanks a lot, Srinivas. this worked! I have used depth first search postorder traversal (fortunately, it is implemented in networkx library and I didn't need to implement it myself). still for me strange that recursion didn't work. it is in a way similair to all recursion problems, where you have some basecase (value of leaf is equal to value of leaf) and then you sum it up recursively brunch by brunch... may be in spare time I try to solve it again with recursion... have a nice day and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Some initial code would have been nice to have, but this is my shot.

Will this work?

```
 #Assuming you've defined root, leaf as special subclasses of type node. 
    #With the root having no proportion attrib set.

 def answer(node):
    if not node: # no tree
        return 0
    if node.children = []: # leaf
        return node.value
    value_list = []
    for child in node.children:
        value_list.append(child.proportion * answer(child))
    node.value = sum(value_list)
```

**Explanation:** Consider a structure like the one you've outlined.

Call the answer function with the root `answer(root)` . 
This in turn calls it on `b` who calls it on `e`. `e` is a leaf who returns its value. Then `f`. Function backtraces to `b` who now has the value `5.7`. So on and so forth..

Comment: Thank you, Srinivas. For some reason it doesn't work. Please, take a look at edited question. I put code there.